# How can I pass variable inside k8s module to another yml as parameter

Tags: kubernetes, parameters, ansible, yaml, persistent-volumes

I want to pass variable to another yml from ansible k8s module

```
- name: Create a Secret
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Create minio-pvc
      k8s:
        state: present
        kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
        namespace: "{{ item.namespace }}"
        src: /tasks/minio-pvc.yml
      with_items:
        - { namespace: demo1}
        - { namespace: demo2}
        - { namespace: test}
```

This is the yml file that I want to send param inside. So I can create 
PersistentVolumeClaim dynamically.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  annotations:
    pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: "yes"
    pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: "yes"
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: minio-storage-claim
  name: minio-pv-claim
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/demo/persistentvolumeclaims/minio-pv-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  volumeName: $param(which must be in here)
```

something like this;

```
        namespace: "{{ item.namespace }}"
        src: /tasks/minio-pvc.yml
        param: "{{ item.param }}"
      with_items:
        - { namespace: demo1 , param: pv1}
        - { namespace: demo2 , param: pv2}
        - { namespace: test , param: pv3}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below.

```
- name: Create a Secret
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Create minio-pvc
      k8s:
        state: present
        kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
        namespace: "{{ item.namespace }}"
        definition: "{{ lookup('template', '/tasks/minio-pvc.yml') | regex_replace('\\$param', item.param) }}"
      with_items:
        - { namespace: demo1, param: pv1 }
        - { namespace: demo2, param: pv2 }
        - { namespace: test, param: pv3 }
```

Comment: When I try an error occurs                                                                                                failed: [127.0.0.1] (item={'namespace': 'asd', 'param': 'pv0002'}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": {"namespace": "asd", "param": "pv0002"}, "msg": "Error accessing apiVersion: v1...  resources:\n    requests:\n      storage: 5Gi\n  volumeName: pv0002. Does the file exist?"}

Comment: it puts yaml file inside this yaml. But I need to show source to execute that yaml.

Comment: Change src to definition. Updated my answer.

Comment: it does "resource_definition": "apiVersion: v1\nkind: PersistentVolumeClaim\nmetadata:... accessModes:\n  - ReadWriteOnce\n  resources:\n    requests:\n      storage: 5Gi\n  volumeName: pv0004",

Comment: Thanks to you I found. just I changed metadata: name: too as dynamically like you wrote. And it works now.

Comment: Yes, the name should be unique, even across the namespaces.